# Typescript: How to reference other prop of literal object, from within the object?

Tags: typescript, self-reference, object-literal

How can I self reference a prop in typescript?

```js
const Test = {
    a: { someProp: true },
    b: { ...Test.a, someOtherProp: true } //error: Block-scoped variable 'Test' used before its declaration.

}
```

here is a [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgU2jAvDA3gKBjmBDALgxghAFsEAFAJxAAcipqBXBGAXwBptcAjI9DAB0IxNCF5OJcggDyUABYJqNeoxZt2mdkA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a getter:

```
const Test = {
    a: { someProp: true },
    get b() {
       return  { ...Test.a, someOtherProp: true }
    }
}
```

(This problem is not specific to TypeScript—it's how JavaScript works)